# ProbabilityDistribution[] function just hangs

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

I have this discrete probability function that I want to utilize with Mathematica's
`ProbabilityDistribution[]` function

The distribution is:

```
Pn[0, \[Alpha]_] := 1 - \[Alpha];
Pn[1, \[Alpha]_] := (1 - \[Alpha]) (E^\[Alpha] - 1);
Pn[n_, \[Alpha]_] := (1 - \[Alpha])*
   Sum[E^(j*\[Alpha])*(-1)^(n - 
        j)*(((j*\[Alpha] + n - j)*(j*\[Alpha])^(n - j - 1))/(n - j)!), 
         {j, 0, n}]; 

f[k_] := Pn[k - 1, \[Alpha]]/Sum[Pn[j, \[Alpha]], {j, 0, k - 1}] - 
  Pn[k, \[Alpha]]/Sum[Pn[j, \[Alpha]], {j, 0, k}]
```

and I would like to use other statistics functions like `MomentGeneratingFunction[]`,
`ProductDistribution[]`, etc.

When I type in this:

```
pmf = ProbabilityDistribution[f[k], {k, 1, 20}];
```

It just hangs and does nothing...I've waited for over an hour sometimes...I don't even know if I can do this.

Is there a better way to do this? I.e., create a pdf using the function above

Comment: Your `f[k]` seems quite computationally demanding to me. Have you tried calculating a few values for it on its own, to check whether it is the cause of the hang? Is `f[k]` already normalized?

Comment: Yes I have - `Sum[f[k], {k, 1, 20}] /. {\[Alpha] -> 0.5}` computes quickly...

Comment: I am unclear precisely what you mean by normalization, but the pmf does sum to (almost) 1 - even for `{k, 1, 20}`. Theoretically, the support is $[1,\infty]$

Comment: Evaluating `Sum[f[k] /. α -> 7/8, {k, 1, 20}] // Simplify // N[#, 20]&` shows that either `{k, 1, 20}` is not a valid range for the distribution or that the distribution needs to be normalized. Note also that `ProbabilityDistribution` is not a "pmf" but rather a distribution, call it `dist[α]`. Then the "pmf" is given by `PDF[dist[α], x]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Start by preventing `Pn` from evaluating unless `n` has a nonnegative integer value.

```
Pn[0, α_] := 1 - α;
Pn[1, α_] := (1 - α) (E^α - 1);
Pn[n_Integer?NonNegative, α_] := (1 - α)*
  Sum[E^(j*α)*(-1)^(n - j)*(((j*α + n - j)*
    (j*α)^(n - j - 1))/(n - j)!), {j, 0, n}]

f[k_] := Pn[k - 1, α]/Sum[Pn[j, α], {j, 0, k - 1}] - 
  Pn[k, α]/Sum[Pn[j, α], {j, 0, k}]
```

Checking the total probability,

```
Sum[f[k] /. α -> 7/8, {k, 1, 20}] // Simplify // N[#, 20] &

(* 0.99852321012132571990 *)
```

Since the total probability for `{k, 1, 20}` does not equal `1` (and the discrepancy worsens for larger `α`), the distribution must be normalized.

```
dist[α_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
   f[k], {k, 1, 20, 1},
   Assumptions -> {0 < α < 1},
   Method -> "Normalize"];
```

Verifying that the total probability is `1`

```
dist[α] /. ProbabilityDistribution -> Sum // Simplify

(* 1 *)
```

For symbolic values of `α` computations are very complicated, e.g.,

```
LeafCount[Mean[dist[α]] // Simplify] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.5569, 3616} *)

LeafCount[MomentGeneratingFunction[dist[α], t] // Simplify] // 
  AbsoluteTiming

(* {31.216, 5629} *)
```

For numeric values of `α` the computations are more responsive

```
Mean[dist[#]] & /@ Range[0.1, 0.9, 0.1] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.21928, {1.10051, 1.20419, 1.31467, 1.43658, 1.57661, 1.74568, 1.96436, 
  2.27823, 2.77035}} *)

Variance[dist[#]] & /@ Range[0.1, 0.9, 0.1] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {2.97234, {0.101521, 0.212579, 0.345012, 0.51682, 0.760525, 1.14449, 1.83958, 
  3.37093, 7.15482}} *)

MomentGeneratingFunction[dist[0.5], t] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.12198, 
 E^t (0.606531 + 0.264003 E^t + 0.0910935 E^(2 t) + 0.0274169 E^(3 t) + 
    0.00784581 E^(4 t) + 0.0022263 E^(5 t) + 0.000632653 E^(6 t) + 
    0.000180012 E^(7 t) + 0.0000512389 E^(8 t) + 0.0000145858 E^(9 t) + 
    4.15209*10^-6 E^(10 t) + 1.18197*10^-6 E^(11 t) + 
    3.36467*10^-7 E^(12 t) + 9.57826*10^-8 E^(13 t) + 
    2.72672*10^-8 E^(14 t) + 7.75901*10^-9 E^(15 t) + 
    2.19825*10^-9 E^(16 t) + 6.3983*10^-10 E^(17 t) + 
    1.56433*10^-10 E^(18 t) - 6.36646*10^-12 E^(19 t))} *)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!